# Best way to accees NAS in java: Mount using external Linux command "mount"

Tags: java

I need to store files on a network drive (MyBook Live). At the moment i'm doing this:

```
String cmd = "mount //192.167.0.3/Public/Folder /media/Folder -o user=test,password=test"; 
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime() ; 
Process pr = run.exec(cmd); 
pr.waitFor();
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It is deeply OS dependent, so probably this is the best from java solution.  You might consider an `fstab` entry for the remote filesystem?

Comment: Good point. ANd then just check if the mount was succesful. Thanks!

Comment: Another advantage is that you can specify filesystems in `fstab` to not require root permission to mount... this way you can run your java application with user permission, which is safer and more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the same thing - executing a command to do the mount - for a project I was working on last fall. There are no Java API to do this directly (or any better way as far as I know). It worked properly.

I agree with Bailey S recommendation of an fstab entry - did the same thing.

You might want to read on the pitfalls of using Runtime.exec() and Process.waitFor() (http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=2). I prefer using Apache Commons Exec (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) for executing OS commands.